# When restarting an 2020 Retina iMac after changing RAM, does it chime before or after memory checks?

Tags: mac, imac, hardware, upgrade

I'm aware that the iMac does a memory check when you add/remove RAM and that this can take some time.
My 2020 iMac chimes when you turn it on normally, but when you change RAM should it chime before the RAM check, or afterwards?

I am finding that when I install additional DIMMs I get no chime and nothing happens for several minutes. If I remove the new DIMMs it restarts normally with no noticeable delay. No chime means I don't know how far it has got; I would expect some sort of beeping if it found a problem?

Comment: My 2019 iMac didn't chime when I added RAM.  The 2020 iMac is particularly picky about what memory configuration works - most reliable if all 4 slots have identical RAM (size and manufacturer).